# FMDB stringForColumn Returning nil

Tags: ios, nsmutabledictionary, fmdb

I am looping through a FMDB result set, generated from a SQLite3 database, creating objects to use later. 
The data content is created by various users, using various text editors and encodings.

A few records are problematic, returning nil for the column value, even though there is text in the column.

For example I see the text for a column  in the database when I run a commandline query but FMDB method stringForColumn is returning nil. I also see that the potential cause is high ascii characters in the column content, that most likely got there by a user copying and pasting text from MS Word. My question is what is the best way to deal with this type of "dirty" data, realizing that some of the data may be in the database with these characters?

[image]

```
NSMutableDictionary *words = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
FMResultSet *rs = [db executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM `foo` WHERE 1"];

while ([rs next]) {
    Word *myWord = [[Word alloc] init];  

    //Coming in as a nil value eventhough there is text in the database column
    [myWord setDefinition:[rs stringForColumn:@"definition"]];

    [words setObject:[myWord definition] forKey:[myWord term]];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Even though you have various users entering code from multiple text editors, and encodings, they would have to be normalized to the encoding that the DB was set to.
Seems like this maybe related to FMDB not properly handling the translation of the encoding stored in the DB.  Maybe since you know the encoding of the data, you can pull the 
contents and do your own "translation"?  Try pulling data directly using using dataForColumn, or UTF8StringForColumnIndex, and see what you get.

As an aside, the "where" isn't wrong, but I would say that it is superfluous.  I would also add that since it serves no purpose it may mislead or confuse those not as fluent in sql.

Answer (score -3):

The "Where" in your select statement is incorrect.

Comment: No, it isn't. I suggest that you check out the SQL specification or simply run it yourself.